# Minor changes in indexing take twice memory and time

Tags: c, performance

I submitted two slightly different solutions for a problem in which you have remove duplicate elements of an array, so that the relative order does not change.

In [first](https://codeforces.com/group/ID2BqCQl2p/contest/312934/submission/105215830)  method, I take input sequentially, and store in an array sequentially, and then two nested loops, to check for each element in input array, if it is unique, I store it in another array.

While in [second](https://codeforces.com/group/ID2BqCQl2p/contest/312934/submission/105216584) method, I take input sequentially, but store then in reverse order. Rest is same, except the required indexing/iterator changes.

The second one takes twice as much time and memory as first.
Though, the difference is very minor, then **why** is there a huge difference in time?

Or **How** can I check exactly why is there this difference?

---

**Actual Problem:** You are given an array a consisting of n integers. Your task is to make these array unique by removing duplicates from them.

You have to leave only the rightmost occurrence for each element of the array and remove all other occurrences. The relative order of the remaining unique elements should not be changed.

**First method** (15 ms, 4 KB):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, c;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    int arr[n], nondupe[n];
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%i", arr + i);   // Store sequentially
    
    int k = n - 1;
    nondupe[k--] = arr[n - 1]; // add last element in non-duplicate array (because rightmost entries are required)
    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        for (c = n - 1; c > k; c--) // Nested loops to iterate over all elements in both arrays
            {
                if (arr[i - 1] == nondupe[c])
                    break;
                if (c == k + 1)
                    nondupe[k--] = arr[i - 1];
            }
    printf("%i\n", n - k - 1);
    for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
        printf("%i ", nondupe[i]);
}
```

**Second** (30 ms, 8 KB):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, c;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    int arr[n], nondupe[n];
    
    for (i = n; i > 0; i--)
        scanf("%i", arr + i - 1);
    
    int k = 0;
    nondupe[k++] = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (c = 0; c < k; c++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == nondupe[c])
                    break;
                if (c == k - 1)
                    nondupe[k++] = arr[i];
            }
    printf("%i\n", k);
    for (i = k; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%i ", nondupe[i - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Code needs to be in the post and not as external links. Especially for links that require login!

Comment: I thought It'd unnecessarily lengthen the question.

Comment: `The second one takes twice as much time and memory as first` What is used to measure time and memory?

Comment: @KamilCuk, It shows on the codeforces website

Comment: In the first code, when looking at element `arr[i]`. you have already processed all elements to the right of it. If the element is unique, that is after you are done looking at `a[i]`, you store it to `nodupe` at an index not less than `i`. That means that you need only one array. (You can verify that by making `arr` an alias of `nodupe` with `int *arr = nondupe;`) Apparently, the compiler can see this opportunity for optimization and creates only one array.

Comment: (But the second code has that property, too. I can only guess that the line `nondupe[k++] = arr[0];` prevents optimization. I'd get rid of that line, but your code requires it, because you do the assignment of a now unique element inside the inner loop, so that no new elements would be added if `k == 0`. That assignment with the additional test in the loop looks somehow unconventional. I'd refactor the hit test into a separate, possible static, function.)

Comment: @MOehm, Yes that makes sense. Didn't know compilers can optimize code like this too. Thanks

Comment: Well, it's just an educated guess. You can always look at the generated assembly code to see whether there is really just one array involved.

Comment: @MOehm, `int *arr = nondupe;` 
This line of code says, go at the first element of `arr` and store the pointer `nondupe`? Am I correct?

`Nevermind, I ignored the data type.....`

Comment: It "aliases" `arr` to `nondupe`, so that `arr[i]` and `nondupe[i]` refer to the same element. If you like, it is an explicit "decay" of the array `nondupe` into the pointer to its first element, `arr`.

Comment: @MOehm, got it.

Comment: Indeed, using malloc for both arrays takes 8 KB memory.

Comment: @MOehm, I made a single array version, only thing changed was that I replaced, `nondupe` by `arr` everywhere and `k = n - 2`. This time it took 8 KB. This is even more strange...

Comment: Well, that probably means that my guess above (compiler optimization) wasn't so great. I guess the test case is with 1000 numbers, so 8kb would be what I'd expect. We don't really know how the memory is measured and which optimization settings are used in the online judge. I wouldn't worry about the difference too much.

Comment: @MOehm, Yeah, just this strange doubling made me curious.